# Magento 2 get cached url full path of custom attribute

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I have custom media attribute for hover `hover_image` I would like from list.phtml to get this full path url to cached file.

e.g `small_image` image in list.phtml is:
http://magento2/media/catalog/product/cache/e616f7b3fa3ef730e13c0a1681a4995e/b/l/test.jpg

I need `hover_image` e.g:

http://magento2/media/catalog/product/cache/e616f7b3fa3ef730e13c0a1681a4995e/**firt-letter/second-letter/hover_image.jpg**

How can I do that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this. So this is quite simple:

in view.xml

```
<image id="my_id" type="hover_image">
    <width>xxx</width>
    <height>xxx</height>
</image>
```

in list.phtml

```
 $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
 $productImg = $_imagehelper->init($_product,'my_id')->constrainOnly(FALSE)-
 >keepAspectRatio(TRUE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize(xxx)->getUrl();
```

**Note:** keepAspectRatio, keepFrame, resize can be set in xml too instead.